# How do I delete a parent directory w/o deleting a sub-directory?

Tags: linux, command-line

For example, I have DirectoryA within DirectoryB within DirectoryC (A/B/C).

DirectoryA has some files I'd like to keep, DirectoryB **only** contains DirectoryC, and DirectoryC also has files I'd like to keep.

Is there a way to delete DirectoryB, moving the files from DirectoryC to B? Essentially deleting one level of the directory tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there isn't a file called DirectoryC (going to just call DC) in DirectoryA (going to call DA), move DC into DA `mv ./DA/DB/DC ./DA` and then you can just delete the empty DB `rmdir ./DA/DB`